# Cookie adding another entry instead of replacing existing value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I am using the popular jquery cookie plugin to set a session cookie value via javascript like so:

```
function ChangeLoginUser(sel) {
    var selectedUser = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    $.cookie("LoginUser", selectedUser);
    location.reload(true); //refresh
}
```

This function is called after user selects from a site global drop-down box option.

- Change the value on page1 - the cookie is set CookieName = Value1.
- Go to page2 - The cookie is persisting correctly
- Change the drop-down value to value2 - Fiddler now shows two cookies by the same name with both values like this:

> ```
> CookieName = value2
> CookieName = value1
> ```

I don't understand why this is happening.  I need to keep only one cookie of this name.  The new value is supposed to replace the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It looks like the problem was with the cookie path.  Each URL can have a separate cookie with the same name.  The solution is to set the path to be domain wide like this:

```
$.cookie("LoginUser", selectedUser, { path: '/' });
```

or, if you need to narrow it down to only your application you can do it like this:

```
$.cookie("LoginUser", selectedUser, { path: AppPath });
```

where AppPath can be set in the beginning of your shared layout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AppPath = '@Url.Content("~/")'
</script>
```